# Convert pandas.core.series.Series data from nan to None Django

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a pandas.core.series.Series class

When the field is empty I get 'nan' as a value and like that it stores in database. I want to convert that empty value to 'None' so I can manipulate with None value

What I tried is here

```
import numpy as np
data.replace(np.nan, None, regex=True)
```

But this isn't working. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
import pandas as pd
data = data.where(pd.notnull(data), None)
```